# What control should I use for multiple selection of item in winforms C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am really confused on thinking which control to use for my purpose.

I am having list of items say item1 to item10. User can select 4 or 5 items in any order.

Now user selected items has to be separated in same order.

For example, if the user selected the items in following order, item4, item8, item3 and item2.

I want it in the same order. item4,item8,item3,item2.

How do I achieve this in winforms control?

Comment: Did you try the ListBox control?

Comment: If selection order really matters then it is very important that the user can tell that he selected in the correct order.  And can fix mistakes.  The standard UI for that is *two* listboxes.  One that displays available items, another that shows selected items and order.  Two buttons to move items back and forth between the listboxes.  You have probably seen [this before](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/articles/MultiListBox/MultiListBox.gif).

Comment: Ya i tried listbox as 'hans passant' said. But the problem is I am having lot of other controls in the form page. If i use 2 listbox method, the form page goes down and down as it occupies more portion. Is there any other option possible than 2 listbox method

Comment: You can do it with one list box. If it suites your need let me know for more explanation.

Comment: @RaizeAhamed You could ask over on [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) for ideas if your form space is that limited.

Comment: @Ham3d How is it possible with one listbox. really I need that

Comment: I would go with Hans solution

Answer (score 0):

It is not a very nice solution but I wrote it as you asked.
Set the `SelectionMode` of your ListBox to `MultiExtended` or `MultiSimple` as you need.
Then write this code in `SelectedIndexChanged` event of your ListBox:

```
    List<string> orderedSelection = new List<string>();
    bool flag = true;
    private void listBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            flag = false;
            var list1 = listBox3.SelectedItems.Cast<string>().ToList();
            if (listBox3.SelectedItems.Count > orderedSelection.Count)
            {
                orderedSelection.Add(list1.Except(orderedSelection).First());
            }
            else if (listBox3.SelectedItems.Count < orderedSelection.Count)
            {
                orderedSelection.Remove(orderedSelection.Except(list1).First());
            }

            var list2 = listBox3.Items.Cast<string>().Except(list1).ToList();
            listBox3.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
            {
                listBox3.Items.Add(list1[i]);
                listBox3.SelectedIndex = i;
            }
            foreach (string s in list2)
            {
                listBox3.Items.Add(s);
            }
            flag = true;
        }
    }
```

When user selects an item, It comes to first of the list and the rest of the items comes next.

Also, there is an alternative way. You can use a `CheckedListBox` with two extra button for moving selected items up and down. So user can change the order of selected items.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses CheckListBox's ItemCheck event along with a private List to keep track of the click items order.

```
protected List<string> clickOrderList = new List<string>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Populate the checked ListBox
    this.checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Row1");
    this.checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Row2");
    this.checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Row3");
    this.checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Row4");
}

private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender != null && e != null)
    {
        // Get the checkListBox selected time and it's CheckState
        CheckedListBox checkListBox = (CheckedListBox)sender;
        string selectedItem = checkListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

        // If curent value was checked, then remove from list
        if (e.CurrentValue == CheckState.Checked &&
            clickOrderList.Contains(selectedItem))
        {
            clickOrderList.Remove(selectedItem);
        }
        // else if new value is checked, then add to list
        else if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked &&
            !clickOrderList.Contains(selectedItem))
        {
            clickOrderList.Insert(0, selectedItem);
        }
    }
}

private void ShowClickOrderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string s in clickOrderList)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(s);
    }

    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
}
```